# How to ignore solid-color image backgrounds when working with convolutional neural networks (CNNs)?

Tags: computer-vision, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

Given an image of an object with a known, solid background color, how can I influence a CNN to ignore/discount the features of the background, thereby emphasizing the object?

For your information, my scenario is feature extraction (e.g. neural codes) for the purposes of content-based image retrieval (CBIR). I am using Caffe.

Answer (score 1):

One option I can think of is creating two inputs per image: the first is your 3xHxW color image and the other is 1xHxW mask with zeros on the background (the "solid-color" pixels) and ones otherwise. Then you can do element-wise multiplication of the mask with the output of your first conv layer, thus forcing all features of "solid-color" pixels to be zero.

Comment: Sounds interesting, thank you. Can I force the pixels to be zero by just replacing the background color with black because it is a zero valued color?

Comment: @E.W. I'm not sure it would work, since you have the constant bias term in the convolution. You also need to take into account the image mean you might be subtracting...

Comment: I am using a particular RGB value as the image mean. If I set the background to the same color as this value, will that de-emphasize it?

Comment: For more information: In my scenario I am using the CNN for feature extraction for the purpose of image search. That is, I'm building up a large database of features of images in the data set, and given a new query, will extract it's features, and then do matching. 

The problem is the images in the database have background colors which are hurting the matching since the features assume the background is relevant. 

So to clarify my question: do you have any advice on how to de-emphasize the background in these extracted features when matching?

Comment: @E.W. even when setting background to mean color, you still have the constant bias term in the convolutions.

Comment: You could use a multi-task learning formulation where you try to estimate class labels and foreground segmentation simultaneously. This is like adding more supervision to your training. One nice consequence is that when doing matching, you will also end up with a foreground segmentation.